# Fade into black jQuery or Javascript effect? Exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, mouseenter

Does there exist some kind of jQuery fade into black effect withing a specific part of a picture. So it really colors the picture into becoming black? I do know about the canvas element, but it just doesn`t seem like a good solution to me, would be grateful with some help :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

applying an overlay to the picture ( an absolutely positioned `DIV` ), and adding `opacity: 0` and `background-color: black` will make a transparent overlay. You can then animate the opacity to 1, basically "darkening" the image progressively.

**Edit:** here's a fiddle with a demo http://jsfiddle.net/FMSKf/

Comment: I see, but what if I wanted to only fade a specific part of an image into a black color? Like a white dot to appear upon hover?

Comment: you then need to adjust the CSS for the overlay. In the provided example it's `top:0; left:0` (ie from topleft corner) with `width:100%; height:100%` (ie covers the full container). You can adjust it to anything and cover any part though.

Comment: I see. Okey, I think I`ve got some information until further problems. I could get back to you, but until then I`ll give you a Green Checkmartk! ;)